# How to customize tfx Evaluator component

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tfx, tensorflow-extended

We are developing a ML pipeline with TFX, the model is a Keras sequential DNN with mostly dense layers. We would like to customize the Evaluator component to compare the blessed and the candidate model by comparing their predictions on a test set of our choice. Therefore given the test set we want to ask both models for predictions and decide which model is the best by using a custom metric.
Based on the official documentation, it seems that we should create a custom python file and provide it to the Evaluator component via the *module_file* parameter, however there are no information about how this file has to be. For example, which are the functions that the Evaluator component calls? (for example the trainer component calls *run_fn*). What output should this function return?

We are using:

- TF Version:  2.6.3
- TFX Version:  1.4.0

Thank you!

Comment: Can you (1) pass example_splits=["test_set_of_my_choice"] (2) define a custom metric in a python module (3) use that custom metric within the vanilla Evaluator via eval_config (see https://github.com/tensorflow/model-analysis/blob/master/g3doc/metrics.md)

Comment: Thank you @MicahSmith ! So if I define my custom metric in eval_config and use the evaluator component in this way:  `evaluator = Evaluator(examples=["test_set_of_my_choice"] , baseline_model=model_resolver.outputs['model'],model=trainer.outputs['model'],eval_config=eval_config)`  then will new predictions also be asked to the blessed model to calculate the custom metric? So if I understand correctly, I just need to edit _eval_config_ without providig the _module_file_ parameter, is it right?

Comment: That's mostly right. `Evaluator(examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'], example_splits=['test_set_of_my_choice'], ...)`. In `eval_config`, you are defining your custom metric in terms of a fully-qualified python module name. So evaluator must be able to import from that module name at least - so you may not need `module_file` depending on whether your metric is importable or not